# Counting incoming mails from Fogbugz

Tags: fogbugz

For analysis purposes, I would like to count how many mails have bee received within my Fogbugz installation for each of `sUser` mailboxes within my `dbo.Mailbox` table.

Is this at all possible?

I had achieved this previously by parsing the mail headers, but it is kind of ugly.